# PhoneGap app crashes after showing memory warning

Tags: ios, css, memory-leaks, cordova, ipod-touch

I am using Phonegap to build iOS app and here am using  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` for native scrolling. So by using the css property is showing **Received memory warning** in Xcode console and crashes in iPod. But it is working fine in simulator and also in iPad. I tried to use **Instruments** to detect the memory issue but did not get any success. After removing the **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** its working fine in iPod. Not able to figure out what is happening.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPod_Touch , only 4th generation and above devices are **properly** supporting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

iOS5 has a technical support for it, but it's very buggy and can cause unwanted behavior on the device.

So my question to you is: which iOS version you're testing on?

And the suggestion is to detect the iOS version and then either apply `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` or to use custom alternative for scrolling, like [iScroll 5 (Beta)](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll)

Comment: I am using iOS 6.1 in the iPod. I tried to use iScroll but that is not working properly as per my page structure. I have 6 different divs which are horizontally placed and all are scrollable and having dynamic content.

Comment: It's good that you mentioned "dynamic content" since it explains things. Check also similar question I made about images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801693/memory-consumption-of-images-in-ios-web-application.

In brief: setting items outside viewport to "display:none" helps. And removing them temporarily from DOM helps even further.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem when I've tried loading to many images on app load. My suggestion is if your app is a scroll based app to implement some form of lazy loading. http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/ This is one good library I've used in the past that allows you to smoothly load data as you scroll.